# android - how use BarcodeDetector to read barcode by pass one barcode image instead of using camera scan barcode

Tags: java, android

how use google Mobile Vision BarcodeDetector to read barcode by pass one barcode image instead of using camera scan barcode ?

Comment: Mobile Vision is no longer maintained, and ML Kit is now recommended as a replacement. They have a helpful [barcode scanner](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes) tutorial.

Comment: thank you! I will try this later!!